# Based on Exodus 3:10, 17, did Moses fulfill his ministry or not?

Tags: exodus, moses

> KJV Exodus 3:
>
> 10,  Come now therefore, and I will send thee unto Pharaoh, that thou mayest bring forth my people the children of Israel out of Egypt.
> ...
> 17, And I have said, I will bring you up out of the affliction of Egypt unto the land of the Canaanites, and the Hittites, and the Amorites, and the Perizzites, and the Hivites, and the Jebusites, unto a land flowing with milk and honey.

Based on the fact that Moses died in the wilderness and could not take the children of Israel into the Promised Land, there has been different interpretations as to whether he fulfilled his calling/ministry or not.  I am of the opinion that even though he did not enter into the Promised Land,  his ministry was fulfilled. I want to know if I'm thinking in the right direction or not. Did Moses fulfill his ministry?

Comment: I am not sure Moses fulfilled his ministry because he couldn't step his feet on the Promised Land.

Comment: Could you explain what it means to "fulfill his ministry?" Where does such a concept come from? Why is it important, and what difference does it make? Is that the same as a person fulfilling his life mission on this world or is it more than that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes he did; but he had to be punished for is anger with his people and not obeying God at Meribah:-

> NWT Numbers 20:12, 13  "Jehovah later said to Moses and Aaron: “Because you did not show faith in me and sanctify me before the eyes of the people of Israel, you will not bring this congregation into the land that I will give them.” 13 These are the waters of Meribah, where the Israelites quarreled with Jehovah, so that he was sanctified among them."

As he was leader of the nation he set a bad example which he had to pay for, but otherwise he was a good man:-

> NWT Numbers 12:3  "Now the man Moses was by far the meekest of all the men on the face of the earth."

and God showed that even though Moses made a mistake God was still going to use him, so we all have a chance dispite our short comings.

> NWT  Hebrews 3:5  "Now Moses was faithful as an attendant in all the house of that One . . ."

Answer (score 0):

Moses was faithful to God by fulfilling the ministry that God had called him to do; bringing the children of Israel out of Egypt into the Promised Land. Even though he made a mistake by disobeying God by **hitting the rock** instead of **speaking to the rock** and God punished him by not allowing him to see the Promised Land he had fulfilled his Ministry and will be saved.

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your answer.  Please take the tour (link below) to better understand how this site works.  Can you support you answer with any references or Bible argument?

Answer (score 0):

> Numbers 32:33
> Then Moses **gave** to the Gadites, the Reubenites and the half-tribe of **Manasseh** son of Joseph the kingdom of Sihon king of the **Amorites** and the kingdom of Og king of Bashan--the whole land with its cities and the territory around them.

The promised land included the territory east of the Jordan. Moses took that land and gave it to Isreal.

Moses didn't die in the wilderness.

> Deuteronomy 34:1 Then Moses climbed Mount Nebo from the plains of Moab to the top of Pisgah, across from **Jericho**. There the Lord showed him the whole land—from Gilead to Dan, 2all of Naphtali, the territory of Ephraim and **Manasseh**, all the land of Judah as far as the Mediterranean Sea, 3the Negev and the whole region from the Valley of Jericho, the City of Palms, as far as Zoar. 4Then the Lord said to him, “This is the land I **promised** on oath to Abraham, Isaac and Jacob when I said, ‘I will give it to your descendants.’ I have let you see it with your eyes, but you will not cross over into it.”
> 5And Moses the servant of the Lord **died there in Moab**, as the Lord had said. 6He buried him in Moab, in the valley opposite Beth Peor, but to this day no one knows where his grave is.

Even though Moses didn't cross the Jordan, he did his job. The rest of the conquest was carried on by Joshua.

> Joshua 21:43 So the Lord gave Israel all the land he had sworn to give their ancestors, and they took possession of it and settled there. 44The Lord gave them rest on every side, just as he had sworn to their ancestors. Not one of their enemies withstood them; the Lord gave all their enemies into their hands. 45Not one of all the Lord’s good promises to Israel failed; **every one was fulfilled**.